# Does accessing a relationship's count fire a fault?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Say I fetch an object called Department with a to-many relationship with Employees (that is, a department has many employees in an `NSSet`). By default, the relationship is first fetched as a fault. If I wanted to get the number of employees, via `department.employees.count` (employees is an `NSSet`), does this cause a fault to fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests, and the answer is **YES**, asking for the count of a relationship does indeed fire faults for objects. I enabled SQLite debugging log, and when I did a normal fetch and did not query the relationship count, it only outputted a couple lines. When I queried for the count of every relationship, I saw several `CoreData: annotation: to-many relationship fault "employees"`.